# How to build (convert from DevCpp) Win32 DLL for SimuroSot simulator using Cmake

Tags: c++, c, dll, cmake, clion

I need to prepare SimuroSot (Robot's soccer simulator) strategy (dll read by this program).
It would be great if I could write it in CLion, but I have no experience with CMake.

Only working version I have is DevCpp project. How to convert it to Cmake?

Project contains:

- Strategy.h with 3 exported functions and some structs.
- Strategy.cpp with DllMain function

It builds files:

- Team2.dll
- libTeam2.a
- libTeam2.def

IMO important options from Strategy.dev:

```
Compiler=-D__GNUWIN32__ -W -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_WINDOWS -D_MBCS -D_USRDLL -DSTRATEGY_EXPORTS_@@_
CppCompiler=-D__GNUWIN32__ -W -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_WINDOWS -D_MBCS -D_USRDLL -DSTRATEGY_EXPORTS_@@_
Linker=-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lodbc32 -lodbccp32_@@_
```

That is my current CMake, Only Team2.dll is created and exported functions are not executed (visible):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(SimuroSotTest)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        library.cpp
        library.h
        )

add_library(Team2 MODULE ${SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties(Team2 PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
target_compile_options(Team2 PRIVATE -D__GNUWIN32__ -W -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_WINDOWS -D_MBCS -D_USRDLL -DSTRATEGY_EXPORTS)
install(TARGETS Team2 DESTINATION /cygdrive/c/Strategy/yellow/)


# CLion does not suppot above "install" so I have to execute it
add_custom_target(
        install_all
        $(MAKE) install
        DEPENDS Team2
        COMMENT "Installing ${PROJECT_NAME}"
)
```

library.h:

```
#ifndef Strategy_H
#define Strategy_H

#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the STRATEGY_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. this symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see
// STRATEGY_API functions as being imported from a DLL, wheras this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef STRATEGY_EXPORTS
#define STRATEGY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define STRATEGY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

typedef struct
{
    double x, y, z;
} Vector3D;

typedef struct
{
    long left, right, top, bottom;
} Bounds;

typedef struct
{
    Vector3D pos;
    double rotation;
    double velocityLeft, velocityRight;
} Robot;

typedef struct
{
    Vector3D pos;
    double rotation;
} OpponentRobot;

typedef struct
{
    Vector3D pos;
} Ball;

typedef struct
{
    Robot home[5];
    OpponentRobot opponent[5];
    Ball currentBall, lastBall, predictedBall;
    Bounds fieldBounds, goalBounds;
    long gameState;
    long whosBall;
    void *userData;
} Environment;

/* MUST BE IMPLEMENTED */
extern "C" STRATEGY_API void Create ( Environment *env );
extern "C" STRATEGY_API void Strategy ( Environment *env );
extern "C" STRATEGY_API void Destroy ( Environment *env );

#endif // Strategy_H
```

library.cpp:

```
#include "library.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule,
DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
        LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
break;
}
return TRUE;
}

extern "C" STRATEGY_API void Create ( Environment *env )
{
    // allocate user data and assign to env->userData
    // eg. env->userData = ( void * ) new MyVariables ();
}

extern "C" STRATEGY_API void Destroy ( Environment *env )
{
    // free any user data created in Create ( Environment * )

    // eg. if ( env->userData != NULL ) delete ( MyVariables * ) env->userData;
}

extern "C" STRATEGY_API void Strategy ( Environment *env )
{
    env->home[0].velocityLeft = 100;
    env->home[0].velocityRight = 100;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem was I compiled it as 64 bit dll.**

I also changed Cygwin to MinGW, so my CMakeLists.txt looks now as follow:

The essence are -m32 options (Windows style paths are because of MinGW)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(SimuroSotTest)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        library.cpp
        library.h
        )

add_library(Team1 MODULE ${SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties(Team1 PROPERTIES PREFIX "" COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
target_compile_options(Team1 PRIVATE -DSTRATEGY_EXPORTS)
install(TARGETS Team1 DESTINATION C:/Strategy/blue/)


add_library(Team2 MODULE ${SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties(Team2 PROPERTIES PREFIX "" COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
target_compile_options(Team2 PRIVATE -DSTRATEGY_EXPORTS)
install(TARGETS Team2 DESTINATION C:/Strategy/yellow/)


# CLion does not suppot above "install" so I have to execute it
add_custom_target(
        install_all
        $(MAKE) install
        DEPENDS Team1 Team2
        COMMENT "Installing ${PROJECT_NAME}"
)
```